# Trouble understanding llvm.global.annotations

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to understand the global annotations which I get with a kernel from llvm but I am kinda confused on a couple of things.

```
@sgv = internal constant [4 x i8] c"222\00"
@fgv = internal constant [0 x i8] zeroinitializer
@lvgv = internal constant [0 x i8*] zeroinitializer
@llvm.global.annotations = appending global [1 x { i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i32 }] [{ i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i32 } { i8* bitcast (void (float addrspace(1)*, float addrspace(1)*, float addrspace(1)*)* @add_kernel to i8*), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @sgv, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([0 x i8]* @fgv, i32 0, i32 0), i8* bitcast ([0 x i8*]* @lvgv to i8*), i32 0 }], section "llvm.metadata"

define void @add_kernel(float addrspace(1)* %out, float addrspace(1)* %in1, float addrspace(1)* %in2) #0 {
```

So I can understand the sgv, fgv & lvgv part. However, when I am looking at the global annotations the parts I am confused about it is this.

```
[1 x { i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i32 }] -- what does the first list mean
[{ i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i32 } --> This part before the kernel. What does this signify.
i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @sgv, i32 0, i32 0), --> In this part am
assuming the i32 0, i32 0 refer to the GEP indexes ?
```

I need a little more explanation on how this annotation is structured and what is the use of this global annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the part which confuses you is the literal struct - which starts with the struct's type and follows with constants for all the struct's field. 4 of these constants are [constant expressions](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions).

Here's a basic breakdown of the AST (not including `[`, `{`, `}`, `]`, and `,`) - click for larger version:

[image: An AST breakdown]

I was too lazy to drill down into the constant expressions as well - but they are basically all in the format `<type> <instruction> ( <instruction args>... )` - see more in the language reference.